# What is the plural of the word "it's"?

Tags: grammatical-number

What is the plural of the word "it's"?

Perhaps "it'ss" or "it'ses"?

Usage: "The paragraph contained three it'ss"
Meaning: "The paragraph contained three occurrences of the word, it's"

Comment: The plural of *it’s* is *they’re*.

Comment: [Plural of words ending in s](https://www.google.com/search?q=plural+of+words+ending+in+s) - I suggest you also visit [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4):

I think that the most elegant solution is to consider "it's" invariable:

> The paragraph contained three "it's".